# Is there a way to configure Alexa smart home skill Auth APIs served on HTTP protocol

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am configuring Alexa smart home skill for Authentication with my cloud under Account linking. As a part of configuration I need to give below two API endpoint of my cloud:

- Authorization URL
- Access Token URI

When I configure my cloud API endpoint which is serving on HTTP protocol it does not allow me to save and give me below error:

> Error: A URL must be between 9 and 2000 characters.

But when I change URL from http to https it allow me to save. So I conclude it only requires endpoint serving on HTTPS.
Question: Is there a way to configure smart home skill with endpoint serving on HTTP protocol?